# Scrapy, extracting empty divs

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am scraping a website that has data points and labels. And they're all in 1:1 ratio. Except some times a data point might be empty. When I run my extract_all() on the selector. I get all the datapoints I want, however it ignores empty strings. I don't want it to ignore those because I get the labels then the datapoints and then sync them together 1 by 1. The problem comes when a div is empty on the page then the sync is lost. How can I add an option to extract_all to return an empty string if there is nothing in the text content area of div. Or a better way to scrape when there are datapoints and labels. I added an image here for when its a perfect record, and then when there is a problem with empty div.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fcd7.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkFI9.png

Answer (score 1):

Just don't extract all. Work with a single data point row:

```
results = []

for data_point_row in response.xpath('//your/xpath/to/select/a/div/or/table/row'):
    label = data_point_row.xpath('./select/a/label').get()
    value = data_point_row.xpath('./select/a/value').get()
    results.append({'label': label, 'value': value})
```